# configure VM to ping a VM in another subnet

Tags: networking, routes, virtual-machine, ping, subnet

I have a rather theoretical question and I am not very experienced with networking:

**Situation:**

- I have 4 virtual machines which have to be configured.
- The OS is freely selectable by me as well as the virtual hardware specs.
- VM 1 is in subnet 1 and is connected to VM2 via LAN and uses VM2 as a standard gateway.
- VM 2 is in subnet 1 and is directly connected to the internet.
- VM 3 is in subnet 2 and is directly connected to the internet.
- VM 4 is in subnet 2 and is connected to VM3 via LAN and uses VM3 as a standard gateway.

**Question:**

How can I configure the VMs so that VM 1 can ping VM 4?

**Thoughts**

I guess I need some kind of routing between VM 1 and 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your current configuration looks like this:

```
VM1 -> VM2 -> Internet

VM4 -> VM3 -> Internet
```

As you stated there is no routing going on between the two subnets, VM2 and VM3 are acting as the router/NAT device for two separate networks. If you want VM4 and VM1 to be able to reach each other they need to be using the same router, so you would have this:

```
    VM1 -> 
           VM2 -> Internet
    VM4 ->
```

Here VM2 is the router/NAT device for VM1 and VM4 (which are on separate networks). You don't need 4 machines to do this unless there is something else specific you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the help. What if i have to use both VM 3 and VM4? Do i have to set a route like "ip route add [IP-VM3] via [IP-VM2]" for VM 1 and vice versa for VM 4?

Comment: In that case both VM1 and VM4 will need two NICs (one on each network) and that would allow you to ping between VM1 and VM4. Or you may be able to have two NICs on VM2 and VM3 and setup static routes to move traffic the way you want. One way or another you need to have a physical connection (or virtual physical) between the two networks.

Comment: Great thanks. 

How would i configure IP, subnet mask and default gateway if i have two NICs for VM2 and 3 and static routes? Something like this?

**VM 1**
IP: 192.168.170.1
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: 192.168.170.2

**VM 2**
IP: 192.168.170.2
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: : ???

**VM 3**
IP: 192.168.171.2
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: : ???

**VM 3**
IP: 192.168.171.1
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: : 192.168.171.2